# Redis multiple databases performance

Tags: performance, redis

If in a single Redis instance I have **N** databases with **K** dedicated connections for each one of the, would that perform worse than having **N * K** connections to a single database?

This would only be for the purpose of better organising keys (it's all **ONE** data set) and `SELECT` would be called only once upon connecting and then each connection would *belong* to a specific database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would perform exactly the same. Please note it does not offer better granularity though (no possibility to save only one database for instance).